# Associative and commutative properties of vector addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, vectors

Is there a semi-rigorous proof that vector addition of plane vectors, "defined" by the algorithm using set square an straightedge, is associative and commutative? I mean for the "proof" to be worded without any coordinate systems or anything of the sort.

This is a little silly question, and I wouldn't be surprised if there was no definite answer. Still, I'm not sure I should mark it as a soft question (but commenters might change my mind).

I believe that the question is partly ill-posed (which is why I say it is silly), but I think it is interesting nonetheless (as many ill-posed questions are).

Answer (score 1):

For the commutative part:

Whichever vector you take first,
you get the far corner of
a parallelogram.
You either
go straight and turn left
or turn left and go straight,
but you end up at the 
far corner either way.

Comment: Yes, essentially, this is a property of parallel lines in Euclidean geometry (and thus actually is problematic in non-Euclidean cases - you can't even easily translate a vector directly to another point in space.)

Comment: Yep. And for associativity, there would be two possible sets of parallelograms, and my mind sort of glazed over, so I just answered about commutativity.